# How to check datatype in graphql query with contentful and gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I have application which gets data from contentful using graphql and gatsby(as ssr), my query looks like:

```
query MyQuery {

 allContentfulModelIntiveStory {
    nodes {
      ourValues {
        childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode {
          learnMoreOptionalText
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it works fine while `learnMoreOptionalText` has a value, but when it is empty i get the error:

```
Cannot query field "childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode" on type "ContentfulPartFeatureSet".
```

To solve it i need to configure database schema in `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
     type ContentfulModelIntiveStory implements Node{
         childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode: Node
      } ...
```

i set `Node` type for it but it didn't work even with deleted cache and restarted server, so here is my question where and how can i check properly datatype of it ?